# Prevent jQuery slidedown menu from pushing down elements in other columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

My current responsive site has slide down menus. I intend to make it so that as the window gets wider the items organize into columns (1,2, and 3). This much is working but when I slidetoggle an element in the first column, the elements in the first column goes down as well. Sometimes the elements hop from one column to the other.

I just need a general idea of what to do?
the menu items are floated
the menus themselves are not

Answer (score 0):

Give your columns a position of relative with some padding and your menus a position of absolute. Then you can position your menu's above the text in the columns, and they won't push the text down when you use slideToggle()

```
.col{
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
}

.menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpDp2/)** to show it in action